# How exactly was Apollo CSM attitude changed (from a current one to a new required one)?

Tags: apollo-program, attitude, guidance

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41158/33950) to a related question suggests that the order in which rotations around three principal axes are applied (in order to estimate the conversion of an attitude to a set of roll, pitch and yaw figures) is important.

This leads to another question: *How exactly were CSM maneuvers for the purpose of changing its attitude performed*?

1. Were there three separate consecutive sets of firings of the RCS thrusters (i.e. one firing to rotate around one axis, then firing to come to stop, then another firing around second axis, come to stop, then third firing around third axis, 
   come to stop), or was there a multiple simultaneous firing of various RCS thrusters at once (i.e. to get to the the new required attitude in one go, so to speak)?
2. If it is the former, was there a rule for a specific order to be followed, for example, first Roll, then Pitch, after that Yaw, or maybe first Pitch, then Yaw  after that Roll?

   ---

Let's consider a particular example from [Apollo 11 Flight Journal](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/05day2-mcc.html). Capcom Bruce McCandless at 025:49:20 into the flight gives PAD for Midcourse Correction burn number 2. The Journal editors give the following interpretation for the spacecraft attitude:

> Spacecraft attitude: Roll, 277°; Pitch, 355°; Yaw, 15°. This is with respect to the attitude of the guidance platform, itself aligned to the PTC REFSMMAT.

If I understand the quote correctly, then regardless of current CSM attitude, at the end of the maneuver, the spacecraft will have to be positioned at Roll 277°; Pitch, 355° and Yaw, 15° with respect to the corresponding axes of the current alignment of the guidance platform.

I assume the astronauts just plug in the numbers in DSKY, and computer does the calculation to get them from whatever their current attitude is to the required one.

Comment: In a perfect world all masses of the CSM would be balanced with respect to all three axes of the spacecraft and all RCS thrusters would be perfectly oriented and would deliver equal thrusts. But in real world there are errors of balance and orientation and thrust forces. I wonder if the computer acheived an acceptable orientation error with only a pair of firings for each axis. Rotating around one axis may cause unwanted rotations around the other axis.

Comment: @Uwe Maybe there was a procedure to "trim the residuals" after maneuver finishes (like a very fine final positioning after the spacecraft comes to a stop, I don't know). The focus of my question though is on the bulk of the attitude change maneuver. How exactly was it performed?

Comment: It's not that the order of *spacecraft* rotations matters, it's that the order of *rotations* matters.  This is because the group of rotations in 3d-space, $\mathrm{SO(3)}$, is not abelian: it's a fundamental property of the space we live in.

Comment: In practice, the order of rotations matters only for large rotation angles. For small angles, all rotation sequences give approximately the same results, and the exact sequence can be ignored. So if you can get the spacecraft close to the target orientation, then you can accurately finish off by simultaneously controlling all axes, it seems... And if simultaneous axis control is enough to get you from the large-angle region to the small-angle region, then you might get away with always applying simultaneous control about all axes...

Comment: @Alex sounds like you are confused about what a single axis rotation is.

Comment: @Organic Marble Explain? I'm using "axis" to refer to roll, pitch, and yaw axes. At sufficiently small angles, it matters little which roll-pitch-yaw sequence you choose. This is presumably because a small rotation has a negligible impact on the following rotations in the sequence. Rolling your reference frame by 1 degree about the x axis leaves the pitch and yaw axes nearly unchanged, with only a trivial error. The smaller the angle, the less the order of rotations matters. And if the order doesn't matter, then simultaneous roll, pitch, and yaw are as good as a roll-pitch, and yaw sequence.

Comment: Found an even better reference for the GNC calculations (given in next comment): , which shows in excellent detail how the calculations were done. It seems in fact Euler angles were converted to a rotation matrix which was then converted to an axis-angle parameterization, in which the axis was resolved into x, y, and z components using precise calculations or approximate calculations. The approximate calculations are described as valid for small angles, because in that limit the conical path traced by a 3D rotation reduces to a nearly planar (2D) rotation...

Comment: Reference for GNC calculations mentioned above: https://strives-uploads-prod.s3.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/19620002325/19620002325.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIASEVSKC45ZTTM42XZ&Expires=1597823138&Signature=SaQ%2F5FHHpAGuLqvRsyHTW9K8Eag%3D. Notice the paper is for the 4-gimbal system considered earlier in the Apollo mission but later replaced with a 3-gimbal system. Still, the drop of one gimbal axis wouldn't force a change in the fundamentals of how the calculations were done...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A single axis rotation (SAR) was performed from the initial to final attitude, unless they were avoiding gimbal lock, in which case it was split into two rotations.

> It  has  been  shown  in  MIT/IL  Report  E-1832  that  it  is
> convenient  to  perform attitude   maneuvers   by   simultaneous
> maneuvers   in   three   axes. However,   under   certain circumstances
> this  leads  to  maneuvers  through  the  area  of  gimbal  lock
> warning  on  the Inertial   Measurement   Unit. In  this  event  the
> maneuver  is  split  into  two  parts  such that  the  gimbal  lock
> area  is  avoided.
>
> The  inputs  to  the  attitude  maneuver  computation  are  the  three
> gimbal  angles desired   as   the   final   orientation   of   the
> spacecraft with   respect   to   the IMU  stable  member. In   order
> to   convert   from   spacecraft   axes   to   control   axes,   all
> outer   gimbal   angles   are modified   by   the   7. 25 degree
> reaction  jet  offset.The  rotational  rate  to  be  used  by  the
> maneuver   is   also   required.
>
> From  the  present  gimbal  angles
> and  the  required  final  gimbal  angles  a  rotation matrix   is   computed   which   describes   the   transformation   from   the   initial   to   the   final attitude. From   this   matrix   the  eigenvector   giving   the   direction   of   required   rotation is  derived   by   partitioning   the   matrix   into   its   symmetric  and   antisymmetric   components. The   equivalent   angle   of
> maneuver is   obtained,and  using  the  magnitude  of  maneuver
> rate,   the   time   of   maneuver   is   computed. In  addition,  the
> rotation  vector  of  the maneuver   rate   is   resolved   into   the
> three   control   axes   of   the   spacecraft.
>
> The   inputs   from
> the   maneuver   computation   program   to   the   Reaction   Control
> System   being   described   are   these   three   spacecraft   rates,
> and   the   time   of   maneuver. Where   gimbal   lock   is   to   be
> avoided, the  two  component  maneuvers  are  sent  to  the control
> system    separately.

[Apollo GNC](http://apollo.josefsipek.net/hrst/archive/1151.pdf) paragraph 3.6

Comment: Thank you for the prompt and definitive answer!

Comment: So it seems the GNC takes the specified Euler angles relative to the IMU gimbals, converts the Euler angles to a rotation matrix, then converts the rotation matrix to an axis-angle parameterization, before resolving the axis into the spacecraft's local coordinate system (or frame) in order to partition the reaction control command among the local x, y, and z axes? Thanks for the quote and reference, Organic Marble. Very useful!